# animation control problem

Tags: c#, unity, animation

I have a list of .FBX object.When I drag that .FBX into scene its corresponding inspector Animation component(fig 1) appears but when I drag some other .FBX object into the scene the Animator component(fig 2) is getting added to the scene.Please see the image attached
[image]

Issues Found :
1)fig (1) - When we click on the object and write code to display animation

```
void OnMouseEnter()
{
 animation.Play("DropBothFork01");
}
```

The above code is working
But if we consider fig(2) the code is not working even though adding a animation component.

What will be the issue?Why for each .fbx object when drag into scene the animation and animator component varries.Could you please help me out solving it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you don't have an animator controller on that object (note the 'None' in the Controller slot.)

The long answer is... kinda long. Read my answer here, how to setup an Animation Controller:
[Unable to use Maya animation with scripts when imported to Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/76260/unable-to-use-maya-animation-with-scripts-when-imported-to-unity/77409#77409)

Comment: after giving the animator control stills its not working

Comment: "still not working" could mean anything, what have you done and what is happening

Comment: I have added the controller to the Animator component and written the above code.When i click the space bar the correspondent animation is not getting played.Instead it is continuously playing the animation

Comment: First off, by "the above code" do you mean code from the link I gave? Because I haven't posted any code here. Second, the behavior you describe is most likely because you didn't setup animation states correctly in the animator controller, and I have no idea what you did there.

Comment: No the code which i specified.I have setup the animation state in the animator controller.But still its not working.

Comment: I have another doubt.Suppose if I drag an .FBX object into the scene whether it will display animator or animation component in the inspector ?

Comment: `No the code which i specified` That code will not work, read the link I posted.

Comment: @ jhocking : I read the link which you posted done same as that only

Comment: You just said "No the code which i specified." The link I gave includes an explanation of why your code won't work, so no you haven't "done same as that".

Comment: I just noticed in one of your other questions you set up different animation code, and wrote that correctly http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83150/control-animation-using-animator-control-class I think you're just horribly mixed up about what you're doing; these two questions contradict each other

Comment: Iam having a doubt,Suppose if I drag an .FBX object into the scene whether it will display animator or animation component in the inspector ?

Answer (score 0):

Fig1 has the animation that you call in your code.

Fig2 has an animator component but no animation, this may explain the problem.
try replacing the animator with your animation you want to run then call it in the same way you do in the code related to Fig1.

This is likely something not quite right with the fbx / prefab that contains it.